# List of List C++

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have create a list of point that I get from an image. But the problem that I have many images so I want to create a list of list. My idea is to create a list of string (that contain the name of images) and add the list of point to this list (every image of the string list contain the list of point of that images). I don't know how to do it. this is the first time that I manipulate lists.

This is what i did so far :

```
struct Point
{
    double x, y;
};
list<Point> landmarks;
list<string> image_name;

for (loop over the images that i have in my folder)
{
    for (loop over point in every image in the folder image)
    {
        Point p;
        p.x = it_shapeROI->roi.pXmin;
        p.y = it_shapeROI->roi.pYmin;
        landmarks.push_back( p ); // list of point in one image
    }
     // Here I want to add to the list of string the list of point.
     // So I will have at the end a list of string (image name)
     // that contain for every name a list of point of that images.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, a map in combination with a vector suites your goals:

```html
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Point
{
 public:
  Point(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y){}
 private:
  int _x;
  int _y;
}; 

int main(void) 
{
 std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point> > mymap;
 for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) // Loop over images
 {
  std::vector<Point> pts;
  pts.reserve(10);
  for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) // Loop over points from image i
  {
   pts.push_back(Point(i,j));
  }
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Point> >("filename", pts));
 } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you return 1 from main, just to be different?

Comment: Just to be different from default statement return 0 (Didn't think much about it). I removed the return statement to avoid confusion

Comment: @JanFischer the return value of main() tells the program which called your program if your program closed with an error. return 1; would mean that your program encountered an error which made it stop. return 0 means that your program ended without error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be better to arrange your data within a `std::map`. ([cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map))

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point>> imageMap;
```

Then you need to iterate over all the images within your desired folder (using the API of your underlying OS) and create a list of Points for each image (and insert it to the map with the filename as the corresponding key).

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about

```
struct image
{
  char *name;
  std::vector<Point> coords;
}

std::vector<image> imageList;
```

Comment: Does it really matter if you use char* or std::string if you do not know what else the string is used for?

Comment: Who deletes the string? Is it a string literal? Will the string be modified? Indeed, use std::string when you do not know what the string will be used for.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Point
{
 public:
  Point(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y){}
 private:
  int _x;
  int _y;
}; 

int main(void) 
{
 std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point> > mymap;
 for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) // Loop over images
 {
  std::vector<Point> pts;
  pts.reserve(10);
  for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) // Loop over points from image i
  {
   pts.push_back(Point(i,j));
  }
  mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Point> >("filename", pts));
 } 
}
```

Thanks for help. I try know to get the point from my list to use it in other function :

```
for( map<string, vector<Point> >::iterator iter = mymap.begin(); iter != mymap.end(); ++iter )
                {
                    vector<Point> tempVec = (*iter).second;
                    string Key = (*iter).first;
                    cout << Key;
                    for (unsigned i = 0; i < tempVec.size(); i++)
                    {
                        cout << Key << "    " << tempVec[i].x  << endl;
                    }
                cout << endl;
                }
```

I does not work, it seems because he give me 0 in evry time.